# How to filter results by the value of a property subproperty in a registry

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a migration script and need to copy over the outlook2013 profile to another machine- for that I need the SID of a profile that would be provided (however as the profile is a local one I can't pull the SID from AD, just locally) I could use PSGetSID but I would like to make it in powershell.

I have tried to pull the SID of a set ID in multiple ways to no avail. I'm running Powershell 3.0- closed environment- unable to upgrade.

```
$path= "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
(Get-ItemProperty $path).psobject.properties |
where {$_.ProfileImagePath -like "ID"
```

```
Get-childitem -path $path | Select name | Where-Object {$_.Property.ProfileImagePath -like "ID"
```

```
$RegistryList = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock {
                Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"                
}
$RegistryList | Where ProfileImagePath -eq "c:\Users\$userbackup"
```

Expected results would be a SID of a provided ID.

Comment: In your last example, it seems like `$RegistryList.PSChildName` will provide you with the SID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your first code into:

```
$path= "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*"
$sid = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $path | Where-Object { $_.ProfileImagePath -like "*ID" }).PSChildName
```

<sup>Note: the `\*` at the end of the path enables recursion</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can call .NET directly in PowerShell:

#### 1: Domain User to SID

This will give you a Domain User's SID

```bsh
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "DOMAIN_NAME", "USER_NAME"
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 
$strSID.Value
```

#### 2: LOCAL USER to SID

This does the same as 1, but for non-Domain users

```bsh
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "LOCAL_USER_NAME"
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 
$strSID.Value
```

#### 3: SID to Domain User

If you have a SID, and want the username (including domain), this will do it:

```bsh
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier "ENTER-SID-HERE"
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) 
$objUser.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use wmi here.  You can also pipe to remove-wmiobject to remove the profile.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile | select localpath,sid
```

Get-LocalUser can also be useful:

```
get-localuser | select name,sid
```